# How to sort a dataframe by row names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
  a b c d
b 0 0 0 1
d 1 0 0 1
c 1 0 0 0
a 2 0 0 1
```

How to sort the df by row names like

```
  a b c d
a 2 0 0 1
b 0 0 0 1
c 1 0 0 0
d 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: The only link you need to make for the marked duplicate is your "row names" are, in fact, the dataframe's `index`. Indexing has a special purpose in Pandas, you can read up more in the official docs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sort_index`:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sort_index` method. Also, you have to pass `inplace=True` *property* in order to operate in place.

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```